# document and image onclick priority

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I have a document. I can't change it.
It has an image.
Image has onclick event (imageCallback).

Also I have a bookmarklet. I want to do `document.onclick = documentCallback;`
And I want to make `documentCallback` have priority: it should runs first. And `imageCallback` shouldn't run at all until I close the bookmarklet.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

delete your imageCallback-function, and lookup the event-Source in your document.onclick:

html:

```
<img id="id-of-your-img" src="...">
```

javascript:

```
document.onclick = function (event) {

  // do what needs to be done first

  //do whatever you want to do when the img was clicked
  if(event.srcElement.id === 'id-of-your-img') {

  }
};
```

edit (i think i know now what you want to achieve (the hint "bookmarklet" was important):

```
var yourimg = document.getElementById('your-img-id')
  , imgCallback = yourimg.onclick;
yourimg.onclick = function () {};

document.onclick = function (event) {

  // do what needs to be done first

  if(event.srcElement === yourimg) {
    imgCallback();
  }
};
```

what is done here? we get the image, overwrite the current click handler (but save it into our  imgCallback-Var. when the document is clicked, we do whatever we want to do, and then take a look if the event-source was our image. if so, we execute our imgCallback-Function.

Comment: Can I do it without deleting image callback? Modifying of source page is not good for bookmarklet.

Answer (score 1):

Add the event handler through addEventListener and set useCapture parameter to true:

```
document.addEventListener('click', documentCallback, true)
```

Events can be dispatched in two phases, the bubbling phase and the capture phase, the capture phase comes first, you should [Take a look at this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)